# console.log() is not logged in Google Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

```
function hi()

{

 console.log('ok')   
}

hi();
```

The output is `undefined` and console is  not showing 'ok
'

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

[image]

You see it logs "ok" and then "`undefined`", which is the result of the function `hi` because it doesn't return anything.

My guess is the `console.log` output is being filtered. See in the screenshot where it says "Default levels"? Click that dropdown and make sure "Info" is checked.

Comment: Yes Default levels are overridden by the filter sidebar,

Thank you